# Is my way of thinking correct?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

> True or false:
>
> 1. If $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ then the function $g(x,y)=f(2x,2y)$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$.

I think it is true. We can define $h(x,y)=(2x,2y)$ then
$g=f\circ h$.
$h$ is also continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ therefore $g$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ as a composition of continuous functions at $(x_0,y_0)$.

> 2. If $\sum \sqrt{a_n}$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

I guess it is also true>
We have $\lim \sqrt{a_n}=0$ then by def for $\epsilon=1$ there is N such that for $n > N \in N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ :
$|\sqrt{a_n}|<1$
So
$0\leq |a_n|<\sqrt{a_n}<1$

So by the comparison test $\sum a_n$ converges.

What do you think?

Comment: Let's make it simpler... if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ then is $g(x)=f(2x)$ continuous at $x_0$?  Consider... $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if }x<2\\2&\text{if }x\geq 2\end{cases}$.  Is $f(x)$ here continuous at $x=1$?  Is $g(x)$ here continuous at $x=1$?

Comment: To emphasize... $f$ being continuous at a specific point is not the same thing as $f$ being continuous in general at *all* points.

Comment: Yeag right!! So I need to add that we are talking about the specific point $(x_0,y_0)$ right? @JMoravitz

Comment: Read my first comment again more closely and read what you are proposing again...

Comment: If a function $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ then the function $g(x,y)=f(2x,2y)$ is continuous at $(x_0/2,y_0/2).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false. Consider function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(2-x)(2-y)}$ at point $(1,1)$

Comment: Thanks, What about tge second claim? Is what I did fine?

Comment: @Bestmat: your work for the second claim looks fine to me

Comment: We have that $a_n\geq 0$ right so the series can be well defined?

Comment: Yes, otherwise $\sqrt{a_n}$ would not make sense